DirectX 11: Line List is drawn 2 pixels wide
I have ported an D3D9 application to DX11 and now I am facing this problem, that the line, that is drawn using a line list of 2 vertices, is drawn with 2px height on screen at certain zoom levels.
Now I know, that this has to do with the rounding of pixels and if the line happens to be in between two pixels, the line is drawn to both pixels. This effect is pronounced when the line is perfectly horizontal like in my case below.
The coordinates are model coordinates, not screen coordinates and a normal WorldViewProjection matrix is used in the vertex shader.
Now when I do a project and unproject on the CPU side before passing the vertices into the vertex buffer (and doing the +0.5 rounding), the effect is gone and it always works.
But that seems wrong and since it always worked in D3D9, I am wondering what has changed since then and what the actual solution is to this problem?



Rasterization rules are not necessarily equivalent (also depend on aliasing, etc.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-rasterizer-stage-rules but for a straight horizontal line it seems a bit strange. Difficult to say w/o any reproducing code.

@SimonMourier thanks for pointing me into this direction. It turns out that in the Vortice library, RasterizerDescription.CullNone (D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC with certain default values) has MultiSampleEnable = true which I didn't know. If I turn that off, the effect is gone. I have to analyze that further. Thanks!
